# filter json object array for unique values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a json object that is an array of arrays. It looks something like this:

```
[{county: Adams, candidate: Smith, votes: 5},
{county: Adams, candidate: Jones, votes: 1},
{county: Clay, candidate: Jones, votes: 7},
{county: Clay, candidate: Smith, votes: 5},
{county: York, candidate: Jones, votes: 10},
{county: York, candidate: Smith, votes: 9}]
```

The array is ordered such that the candidate in each county with the most votes is the first item of that county to appear.

I want to filter the array to just show each county with the candidate who got the most votes.

What's the best way to do that? I tried pop() to get rid of the items with the same county name, but pop just removes the last item in an array. I was looking at splice, but I'm not sure whether there's a more straightforward way to do this.

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myquerypage.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //this is my json array of rows from the dB
        var obj2 = obj;                   //I made a copy of the original json array
        var testString = obj2[0].county;  
        for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) {
            if (obj2[i].county == testString) {
                obj2[i].pop();            //this is wrong
            } else {
                testString = obj2[i].county;
            }
        }

        console.log(obj2);
});
```

Comment: Did you know you're missing a colon (":") in your JSON? It's the third item, in between 'votes' and 7. By the way, if the JSON comes already sorted by (firstly) 'county' and (secondly) 'votes', then you'd simply have to grab the very first item for each county, right?

Comment: @BinaryCat: OK. Corrected. But doesn't matter because the actual array wasn't missing a colon.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of data manipulation, have you thought about including something like [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) to make this easier?

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle I posted. It returns an array of three objects - the one with the most votes for each county.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function like this

```
$.ajax({
url: "myquerypage.php",
method: "POST",
success: function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //this is my json array of rows from the dB
    var distinctObj = obj.reduce(
        function(acc, el){
            var county = acc.set[el.county];
            if (county === undefined){
                acc.set[el.county] = county = {};
            }
            if(county.candidate === undefined){
                acc.result.push(el);
                county.candidate = el;
                county.index = acc.result.length-1;
            }else if(county.candidate.votes < el.votes){
                county.candidate = el;
                acc.result[county.index] = county.candidate;
            }
            return acc;
        },{set:{},result:[]}).result;
    //console.log(distinctObj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(distinctObj));
});
```

**UPDATE**

for output all info you can use something like this

```
distinctObj.forEach(function(el){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(el));
});
```

OR

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(distinctObj));
```

Comment: @LauraNMS yep, in console you can see all objects in this array, what output you need?

Comment: @LauraNMS in your sample console also output array of objects

Comment: I need to see what the objects are (their values)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) version ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aK8L/1/)):

```
// The output
var results = []; 
// Get a list of the unique countys
var countys = _.uniq(_.pluck(arr, 'county'));

// Iterate over the unique countys
_.each(countys, function(county) {
    // Find all the results for this county and save the one with the most votes
    results.push(_.max(_.where(arr, { county: county }), function(result) {
        return result.votes;
    }));
});

console.log(results);
```

You could probably do it more slickly than that with underscore - it's very good for this sort of thing and, as mentioned in the comments, worth looking into further if you're going to be doing a lot of data manipulation.

Comment: says results is [-Infinity]

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me. Is that where you're seeing the infinity result?